# where is the pipeline data stored in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Elasticsearch 5.5.1

I'm using pipeline to parse documents in INGEST node. I simply use api to put my pipeline into ES.

After I restarted the ES cluster (In a bay way, the cluster even become red for a while), I counldn't found my pipeline anymore!

So how is the pipeline data stored?
And how can I make sure my pipeline data is not lost event after my cluster restart?

Comment: Your pipelines are stored in the cluster global state on disk, more specifically in the folder `$ES_DATA/<cluster>/nodes/0/_state` folder.  So you're saying that `GET _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline-id` doesn't return anything? Can you show the commands you used to store your pipeline?

Comment: @Val I figure it out why the data is lost. It's the force restart cause the data lost. The cluster is read for a while. When I try to hot restart the data node, it is ok and it's lost ever.